# Monitor won't wake from sleep over HDMI 2.0

Tags: display, hdmi, sleep

I use two monitors. One is connected by DisplayPort (DP) and one by HDMI. The DP one always wakes from its low power state. If Windows turned off the display due to inactivity, I wake it by moving the mouse. The HDMI one will wake if it is being run in HDMI 1.4 mode. If I run it in HDMI 2.0 mode, it will not wake, unless I power cycle it.

I have tried resetting the monitor to factory specs and updating graphics card drivers.

The monitor works flawlessly over HDMI 2.0 at 4K/60Hz, providing it is never told to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to try a **NEWER** HDMI cable. It is not that the existing cable is broken - just that it is not fully compliant with HDMI 2.0 and might not support all of the signals. Try to find one that was manufactured well after 2015, before concluding that your monitor is at fault.

I am answering my own question as I found the web awash with useless solutions like reinstalling ones OS, checking the cable for damage, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my side. I fixed it by changing the settings on the monitor itself (using the monitor buttons). First I realized that I could manually wake up the screen by pressing the "input select" button. Then, I realized that I could fix the problem by deactiving the auto input select on the screen and I forced it to "HDMI_1" that I use in my case. This solves the problem. Maybe not the best solution as it deactivates the auto input feature of the monitor, but good enough for me as I always use the same HDMI plug on this monitor. I hope it helps!

Comment: This is a really weird and for sure counter intuitive solution, but I'm super glad that it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem with my [G-MASTER GB2888UHSU-B1](https://iiyama.com/gl_en/products/g-master-gb2888uhsu-b1/) in HDMI 2.0 set to 3840 x 2160 @60Hz, my cable is HDMI 1.4, couldn't find a flat one in 2.0.
Anyways when the screen shuts down for any reason and enters power saving mode (the LED indicator switches from blue to orange) it doesn't wake up again unless I set it temporarily at 3840 x 2160 @30Hz then back to 3840 x 2160 @60Hz.

I do it using dc64cmd (12noon's Display Changer) with two batch files (one to disconnect the screen, another one to reconnect it). Download dc64cmd, add it to [windows path variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dut0O.jpg) and use this in a batch file.

To disconnect the monitor:

```
dc64cmd -monitor="\\.\DISPLAY2" -detach
```

To reconnect it:

```
REM First wake it up by setting the refresh rate at 30Hz
dc64cmd -monitor="\\.\DISPLAY2" -secondary -width=3840 -height=2160 -depth=32 -refresh=30 -fixedoutput=default
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL REM Pause for a second
REM set it up again but this time it's awake so put the max rate, 60Hz in my case
dc64cmd -monitor="\\.\DISPLAY2" -secondary -width=3840 -height=2160 -depth=32 -refresh=max -fixedoutput=default
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL REM Pause for a second again
REM move the monitor to the left of the main one and position it so the bottoms are aligned, then "apply" to make sure everything is set.
dc64cmd -monitor="\\.\DISPLAY2" -left
dc64cmd -monitor="\\.\DISPLAY2" -ty=-1080 -apply
```

I'm going to try to find a 2.0 cable though, I hope it'll fix this because even with my batch files it's still a pain in the eema.